# Create Property file inside build.xml

Tags: ant, build.xml

I want to create a .properties file dynamically, and code for the same should be inside build.xml with some values and want to placed it in some directory.

Please Help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [PropertyFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) Ant task, for instance:

```
<propertyfile file="my.properties">
  <entry key="prop.1" value="value 1"/>
  <entry key="prop.2" value="value 2"/>
</propertyfile>
```